# Increasing/Decreasing speed of square

Tags: java, algorithm

here's the Algorithm I wrote for moving a square on a screen, Xcenter and Ycenter are centres of square. speedX is speed in horizontal, and speedY in vertical.

```
while (true) 
             {
                int keyState = getKeyStates();

                // Update the ball's position
                xCenter += speedX;
                yCenter += speedY;
                // Check if the ball hit the bound. 'Reflect' the ball if so.
                if (xCenter > xMax) 
                {
                   xCenter = xMax;
                   speedX = -speedX;
                } 
                else if (xCenter < xMin) 
                {
                   xCenter = xMin;
                   speedX = -speedX;
                }
                if (yCenter > yMax) 
                {
                   yCenter = yMax;
                   speedY = -speedY;
                } 
                else if (yCenter < yMin) 
                {
                   yCenter = yMin;
                   speedY = -speedY;
                }
```

What should be the algorithm to increase the speed. speedX++, just increases in the horizontal direction and hence is not giving the desired result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the direction to stay the same, you'll need to increase both components proportionally.

Comment: I know, but I can't figure out how. If I write x++ first followed by y++, they execute sequentially that is x changes direction first, then y. However, they must occur together

Comment: You should separate the concept of speed from the concept of direction. As it is, if `speedX` is, say, -2, `speedX++` will slow it down to -1. Do it again and the square stops dead (in the horizontal, that is).

Answer (score 0):

You can very well increment/decrement these X,Y positions sequentially. Because setting a variable won't move the square. But When you apply the new position to the Action, Square will go the new place at once.

One more suggestion

When you find the square is going out of boundary, it actually needs to appear from the opposite side. Means `if (xCenter > xMax)` set `xCenter = xMin` and vice versa